# How to display aside menu of metronic angular 7 theme based on logged in user role

Tags: metronic

I am using angular metronic admin template.

We use Angular7 metronic theme for admin template.Here I see how metronic implemented ngx-permissions for routes, but I can’t seem to figure out how to hide menu items based on current userRole.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you for reading this message!!

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: nope, we didnt found any solution for that,since that theme is not supportable for multi role users

Comment: Actually I some how managed to dynamically bind menus based on role access. Simply add a bool property "show" with each route in menu.config.ts and then in binding the menu by enabling/disabling "show" based on the role access.
Lastly, don't forget to add a *ngIf check in the aside-menu component to only render the menu item if the the show property is true.